# Parse Android get Users List

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have this function in my App for making a leaderboard. When executing, it never goes reaches the for loop and I'm unable to update my leaderboard. Is there any better implementation for the same?

```
public void updateLeaderboard(final Context context) {
        Log.d("Leaderboard ", "Updating");
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(KEY_USER_CLASS);
        query.addDescendingOrder(KEY_LAST_LEVEL);
        query.addAscendingOrder(KEY_CROSSED_AT);
        query.whereNotEqualTo(KEY_ADMIN, true);
        query.whereEqualTo(KEY_EMAIL_VERFIFIED, true);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> users, ParseException e) {
                Log.d("Leaderboard ", "done() caled");
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("Leaderboard ", "inside if");

                    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
                        ParseObject user = users.get(i);
                        Log.d("Leaderboard ",
                                "Updating user " + String.valueOf(i + 1));
                        user.put(KEY_RANK, i + 1);
                        user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    Log.d("Leader", "Saved");
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

        Log.d("Leaderboard ", "Closing");
    }
```

Comment: "it never reaches the for loop", which means, I assume, it does reach the `done()` method, but `e == null`. So what about the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: It reaches `Log.d("Leaderboard ", " inside if");`

Comment: Which means your user list is empty, and your query is presumably wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most common cause is not realising that the "User", "Role" and "Installation" classes are special, their actual names are "_User", "_Role" and "_Installation", though to do a query on the User class the recommended method is:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
```

Comment: I did use `ParseUser.getQuery()` earlier, but because I've implemented a login feature in my app, it says not authenticated for all users except the one which is logged in. As you can see in the function, I'll be changing the value of all users. I'll try `_Users` once.

Comment: `User` class is locked down, if you need to have code that modifies other users you'll need to use a Cloud Function and use the master key.

Comment: Oh, Now I'll have to do the JavaScript! :-\ anyways, thanks for the help! :-)

Comment: Can I copy some contents of User class to another class and edit things in the other class?

Comment: Yes, that's an entirely valid way to doing things. If you called your class "Leaderboard" for example, I would suggest having a "user" pointer on it and a "leaderboard" pointer on the user so you can easily query from each side.